# How to pass parameters in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

How should i pass the "type" as a parameter in flutter?
(Android Studio)

I have making an app.
in that working with forgotpasswordpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class second_page extends StatefulWidget {
 var param1,param2;
 second_page(this.param1,this.param2);
@override
_second_pageState createState() => _second_pageState();
}

class _second_pageState extends State<second_page> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(body:Column(children: <Widget>[

  Text("param 1:"+widget.param1),
  Text("param 2:"+widget.param2)
],));
}



}//second page ended


Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: //call on first page using this code
(context)=>second_page("my param 1", "my param 2")));
```

You can pass any kind of type using var parameter

Comment: Thanx..will try this

Comment: let me know the result

Comment: Ya it worked..Thnx